# Delphi 10.2.2 App Tethering with Bluetooth how?

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, tethering

I use app tethering with Delphi between Android and Windows since Seattle and now with Tokyo 10.2.2 and it works quite well across WLAN. The only problems arise from customers that sometime delete custom rules in the Windows firewall so that the devices cannot find each other anymore.

Because of that support effort I would like to additionally offer bluetooth between the two devices but I cannot get it up and running. The Embarcadero documentation is not very helpful either.

What I tried so far (based on the solution working with WLAN):

- Bluetooth Pair the phone with the PC
- Switch both sides from "Network" Protocol (what ist UDP Broadcast) to "Bluetooth"
- Added a Bluetooth component on both sides and activated it (it has no more settings). Also doesnt work without it.

When closing the PC application I get an EBluetoothException saying "cannot establish connection" that's all.

The devices do not discover each other. Perhaps I am missing one important step. So if anyone has bluetooth app tethering up and running I would be grateful if he shared his experiences here!

Thanks!

Comment: There are samples of both tethering and Bluetooth use in the samples that are shipped with Tokyo. Have you tried looking at any of them? Like the *Classic Bluetooth Basic App*, for instance, which describes all that it demonstrates (including discovery and pairing) in a large readme.html file in the app's folder?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately these describe how to pair and discover devices. This also can be done by OS functions and I already paired my Nexus 5 with my PC. I do not find how to use Bluetooth wir App Tethering als the App Tethering examples are working with LAN/WLAN settings and also do not work when switching to Bluetooth. Perhaps I quit App Tethering and program it on my own with Bluetooth...